# How to store a translation in a different table using Doctrine 2 + Gedmo Translatable

Tags: php, doctrine, translation

Using the instructions on https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md#advanced-examples a table can be split in order to store the translations in another table.
 The resulting table structure is:

(example A)

```
 Article             ArticleTranslation
+--------------+    +----------------------+
| id           |    | id                   |
+--------------+    +----------------------+
| title        |    | locale               |
+--------------+    +----------------------+
| content      |    | objectclass          |
+--------------+    +----------------------+
| online       |    | foreign_key          |
+--------------+    +----------------------+
                    | field                |
                    +----------------------+
```

In my view there are two problems using this standard approach:
1. the translated entity is stored into multiple records (one per field) in the translation table
2. The original record should be in the translated table as well.

Is it possible with Doctrine+ Gedmo Translatable to store the translations like this:

(example B)

```
 Article             ArticleTranslation
+--------------+    +----------------------+
| id           |    | id                   |
+--------------+    +----------------------+
| online       |    | foreign_key          |
+--------------+    +----------------------+
                    | locale               |
                    +----------------------+
                    | title                |
                    +----------------------+
                    | content              |
                    +----------------------+
```

So untranslated fields should be in the Article table, translated fields in the ArticleTranslation table with one record per translated article.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: How can I create the behaviour resulting records stored like in example B myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using current architecture it stores a record per field in translation table. In general it was done this way in order to avoid synchronization issues if you add or remove translatable fields from your entities.
Implementation of your method would result in having additional schema migration command specifically for extension or having some magic mapping in background. To avoid confusion the only thing which is scheduled for update is original record translation storage as default locale fallback, without having record in translation table.
I understand that in advanced cases this bahavior is not what you would have done, but it is a behavior for most users which want it configurable as simple as possible.
And regarding collection translations you can use [query hint](https://gist.github.com/1086164) This behavior will never cover 99% of use cases like SF2 does in order to maintain simplicity

Comment: in case of joining 3 level deep things that need translation i believe that this has hudge performance problem

Comment: well, I agree its a bit complex architecture of translatable, though performance also suffers when huge datasets are used. This behavior is more suitable for simple applications. Any big application requires custom solutions to optimize and increase performance. In current case, approach was for simplicity, which does not require entity generators and such, just adding an annotation.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use another solution, you can reuse Sylius translations idea https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.12/book/architecture/translations.html , along with it you will need to copy OrmTranslatableListener to map trait fields